# Pass custom posted variable from a page to Woocommerce order data

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, session, woocommerce

I can add a custom variable to a WooCommerce order, using code like this - but only if the code is on the product page:

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_checkout_url() ); ?>" method="post">   
    <?php
  $value = isset( $_POST['dogname'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['dogname'] ) : '';
    echo '<div><label>Name of Dog</label><p><input name="dogname" value="' . $value . '"></p></div>';
?>  <button type="submit">Checkout</button> 
    </form>
```

But how do I add the data to the order it if I am not on the product page?  I redirect the page after add to cart to a custom page. On this custom page the cart is already populated with the product .  But submitting this form on the custom page - goes to checkout but does not update or add the variable to the order.  How would I update the order with my custom variable from my custom page?

Maybe I need some extra code for the button to update the order on click?

What code would I use for a button - that on click would post the form values to my order, and direct to another page?

Comment: Hi @jon, I tested the code with my single product page, but it redirects to the checkout page too. I guess you used a custom theme or plugin, which changes the default behavior of the product page. You can check the code and apply the same code to other pages.

Comment: the code is not the full code, but the extracted code example that would work on a product page.  I am however trying this code on my custom page - not the product page. I explain the page flow in the question that this code is on my custom page..  The goal is to go to checkout and update/add the custom the order details.  action="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_checkout_url() ); ?>" will direct to chekout.  Im not clear on what you are asking.

Comment: On other pages, do you use GET urls add to cart? Ajax post add to cart? A Post form? Many of those?

Comment: Possible solution : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/332099/how-do-i-add-a-text-input-field-for-customers-to-leave-a-note-on-a-single-woocom

Comment: @MichaelHabib That code doesnt seem to do anything, and its not clear what page that code would come up on, or what button code would trigger any update?

Comment: @Mtxz - as per the code in the question - the form used by woocomerce uses method POST

Comment: @Jon so, you are talking about the add to cart buttons from products list pages? and you dont use ajax add to cart? Or is this a custom form you made to add to cart? The code you shown only display a POST value. Can you add the code of your custom form from you custom page please?

Comment: @mtxz I dont have code for a custom form.  that is the essence of the question.  What is the code of a custom form so I can recreate "add to cart" button from a product page - to a custom page, that is not a product page.  But the content of the form will be added to order details like add to cart on a product page would

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here below is a way to get posted data available in checkout page and anywhere else without loosing this posted data. For that we set the posted data to a WC session variable, so this posted data is available at any moment when needed.

**The form on your page** *(example with multiple fields)*:

```php
?><form action="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_checkout_url() ); ?>" method="post">
    <?php
    $dogname  = isset( $_POST['dogname'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['dogname'] ) : '';
    $dogcolor = isset( $_POST['dogcolor'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['dogcolor'] ) : '';
    ?>
    <div><label><?php _e("Name of Dog");  ?></label><p><input name="dogname"  value="<?php echo $dogname;  ?>"></p></div>
    <div><label><?php _e("Color of Dog"); ?></label><p><input name="dogcolor" value="<?php echo $dogcolor; ?>"></p></div>
    <button class="button" type="submit" name="dog_form" value="submited"><?php _e("Checkout"); ?></button>
</form><?php
```

**The code that set the posted data to a `WC_Session` variable:**

```
// Early enable customer WC_Session
add_action( 'init', 'wc_session_enabler' );
function wc_session_enabler() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() || is_admin() )
        return;

    if ( isset(WC()->session) && ! WC()->session->has_session() ) {
        WC()->session->set_customer_session_cookie( true );
    }
}

// Set posted data in a WC session variable
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'set_custom_posted_data_to_wc_session' );
function set_custom_posted_data_to_wc_session() {
    if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) {
        if ( isset($_POST['dog_form']) ) {
            $values = array(); // Initializing

            if ( isset($_POST['dogname']) && ! empty($_POST['dogname']) ) {
                $values['dogname'] = sanitize_text_field($_POST['dogname']);
            }

            if ( isset($_POST['dogcolor']) && ! empty($_POST['dogcolor']) ) {
                $values['dogcolor'] = sanitize_text_field($_POST['dogcolor']);
            }

            // Set data to a WC_Session variable
            if ( ! empty($values) ) {
                WC()->session->set('custom_data', $values);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.*

**Then you can get that data on any function or template with:**

```php
$values   = WC()->session->get('custom_data');
$dogname  = isset($values['dogname']) ? $values['dogname'] : '';
$dogcolor = isset($values['dogcolor']) ? $values['dogcolor'] : '';
```

**Save that data to order details:**

```php
// Save WC session data as custom order meta data
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'action_checkout_add_custom_order_meta', 10, 2 );
function action_checkout_add_custom_order_meta( $order, $data ) {
    $values = WC()->session->get('custom_data'); // Get data from WC Session variable

    if( ! empty($values) ) {
        if ( isset($values['dogname']) ) {
            $order->update_meta_data( '_dogname', $values['dogname'] ); // Set dog name to order details
        }
        if ( isset($values['dogcolor']) ) {
            $order->update_meta_data( '_dogcolor', $values['dogcolor'] ); // Set dog color to order details
        }
        // Remove the WC_Session variable (as we don't need it anymore)
        WC()->session->__unset('custom_data');
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).

**Then you can get that data from The WC_Order object order using:**

```php
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // If needed, get the WC_Order object from order Id

$dogname  = $order->get_meta('_dogname');
$dogcolor = $order->get_meta('_dogcolor');
```

Like in this hooked function that will display data on "Order received" page:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'thankyou_display_dog_data' ); 
function thankyou_display_dog_data( $order_id ) { 
    
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
    
    $dog_name  = $order->get_meta('_dogname');
    $dog_color = $order->get_meta('_dogcolor');
     
    echo ! empty($dog_name) ? '<p>' . $dog_name .'<p>' : ''; 
    echo ! empty($dog_color) ? '<p>' . $dog_color .'<p>' : ''; 
}
```

Tested and works on last WooCommerce version.

Comment: Thats pretty good stuff - but Im getting an "internal server error" pressing "place order"  button if I include the function - action_checkout_add_custom_order_meta.  Creating the meta data works instead of cart, but I would have to hook it into everywhere the cart data shows - order details/admin/emails etc. Also I see you did a post on changing cart price based on input - Im guessing that will work here.  Thanks

Comment: @Jon Sorry my fault, there was a little oversight in last hooked function, that I have updated now. Everything works nicely. Try it again…

Comment: yes its finalising the order now thanks.  I need to play around with all the hooks to check the data is there to be hooked in.  Great Answer - thanks

Comment: So I am having issues hooking in the data.  I can get the $values to show inside the order, but after "place order" it shows null and the $order gives  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_meta() .  So Im unclear which to use where.  The function I am using that generates this error: add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'dog' );
function dog() {
  $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
  $dogname  = $order->get_meta('_dogname');
  echo $dogname;
}

Comment: @Jon The problem is in your code where you missed to add `$order_id` as function argument in `function dog( $order_id ) {`… I have added a related addition at the end of the answer. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

To add some more functionality to LoicTheAztec answer using his `thankyou_display_dog_data` function.  His included action shows the function on thank you after checkout form

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'thankyou_display_dog_data' );  //add  to admin order data under shipping
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'thankyou_display_dog_data' );  //add  to admin under billing - pick one or duplicate of shipping
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table', 'thankyou_display_dog_data' );  //add to frontend customers my account  
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'thankyou_display_dog_data', 15, 2 );  // add to emails
```